# go gorilla/sessions angularjs and path, session values not saved (find the bug/place the blame)

Tags: angularjs, session, go

Ok where to start...

The problem is when I set the session's `Path` to `"/"` the session doesn't get saved.

And I set `Path` because when posting to a path that is not the path where the session gets saved, aka `session.Save()` is called the session value "user" is empty|nil|not set.
So I set `Path: "/",` but the session isn't saved. When checking Chromium I see that the cookie is set. I don't know where the problem is. Is it in gorilla/sessions? Is it in AngularJS? HTML5 mode is off in angular.

So to rephrase, this happens because `/api/1.0/community` is a different path than `/api/1.0/user` where the `sessions.Save(r,w)` function is called and that's why I set `Path: "/",` . But when `Path` is `"/"` the session value "user" isn't saved.

main.go

```
var (
    sessionStore    *sessions.CookieStore
    sessionAuthKey  []byte      = make([]byte, 64)
    sessionCryptKey []byte      = make([]byte, 32)
    router          *mux.Router = mux.NewRouter()
)

func init() {
    // Generate Session Secret
    sessionAuthKey = securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(64)
    sessionCryptKey = securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32)

    // Create Session
    sessionStore = sessions.NewCookieStore(sessionAuthKey, sessionCryptKey)
    sessionStore.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Domain: ".mango.dev",
        Path:   "/",
        MaxAge: 0,
    }
}

func main() {
    api := router.PathPrefix("/api/1.0").Subrouter()
    api.HandleFunc("/user/register", UserRegisterHandler).Methods("POST")
    api.HandleFunc("/user/authenticate", UserAuthenticateHandler).Methods("POST")
    api.HandleFunc("/user/endsession", UserLogoutHandler).Methods("POST")
    api.HandleFunc("/user/profile", UserProfileHandler).Methods("GET")
    api.HandleFunc("/user/profile", UserUpdateProfileHandler).Methods("POST")
    api.HandleFunc("/user/reset_request", UserResetRequestHandler).Methods("POST")
    api.HandleFunc("/user/reset_password", UserResetPasswordHandler).Methods("POST")
    api.HandleFunc("/user/loginstatus", UserLoginStatusHandler).Methods("GET")
    api.HandleFunc("/forums/directory", ForumsDirectoryHandler).Methods("GET")
    api.HandleFunc("/community/list", CommunityListHandler).Methods("GET")
    api.HandleFunc("/community/show", CommunityShowHandler).Methods("GET")
    api.HandleFunc("/community/create", CommunityCreateHandler).Methods("POST")
    api.HandleFunc("/community/edit", CommunityEditHandler).Methods("GET")

    static := router.PathPrefix("/").Subrouter()
    static.Methods("GET").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("webapp/public")))

    go func() {
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", Log(router)); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    if err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8443", "ssl/mango.dev.crt", "ssl/mango.dev.pem", Log(router)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

handlers.go

```
func UserAuthenticateHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
// ...
    if valid {
        tu.Name = user.UserProfile.Name
        data["user"] = tu
        data["redirect"] = "/user/profile"
        user.Login(r.UserAgent(), r.RemoteAddr)
        session, _ := sessionStore.Get(r, "p")
        session.Values["user"] = user.Id.Hex()
        if tc.Rememberme {
            session.Options = &sessions.Options{
                Domain: ".mango.dev",
                Path:   "/",
                MaxAge: 86400 * 30 * 12,
            }
        }
        session.Save(r, w)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was *dundundun* I had old cookies stored from before the change that had the Path "/api/1.0/user" and apparently this caused a problem since, I imagine, the longer or deeper path has priority over the shorter, root path, which makes perfect sense in retrospect.